Retained Mode GUI in GPU level
Are retained mode guis even possible in the GPU level since every sample i have reviewed has cleared the whole buffer in DX11, OpenGL etc instead of using some kind of layer system to only clear single object. I know that only clearing certain parts of the screen is possible but thats leads to issue of possibly clearing multiple objects if they are stacked on top of each other.
Is there ways of making retained mode gui rendering with layers on GPU level where i could only clear single object using certain id?

Have a read of https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/137543/should-i-use-retained-mode-or-immediate-mode
